# C++ program (XCode) not running until I enter something into console

Tags: c++, xcode, cin, cout

I'm writing a text-based game for a class, and I had the majority of it running and working prior to this issue.

I opened it today and tried to build/run it, and it was built successfully and seems to be running, but some of the first lines of code are outputs to the console, and they aren't happening until I input something into the console, which shouldn't be necessary until after the prompt has printed:

Here's the beginning of my main:

```
int main() {
string name;
cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << "What's your name? ";
cin >> name;
cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');...
```

and here's the output (It's nothing until I've typed in HELP? and pressed enter)

```
HELP?
What's your name? 

===========================================================
|                   Welcome,    HELP?!                    |
===========================================================
```

whereas prior to today, when I'd run it, it'd output "What's your name?", at which point I'd type in my name, and then it'd print the welcome.

I feel like it must be something simple since it seems so black and white to me: Why would it wait for any input when essentially the first real thing I ask of it is to output something to the console? It works this way even if I put a cout statement as the first thing. Is this an XCode problem?

Note: It's treating input like this for every cin in the file as well, the questions and prompts wont print until after I've input something.

Comment: This question is asked _all the time_, but for some reason I can't find a suitable duplicate to categorize it under.

Comment: Yea it seems to me like it'd be common, but I also couldn't find a way to effectively search for this specific issue. Also the answer hasn't worked for me.

Comment: Perhaps the XCode output window is not acting like a normal TTY, and may have its own buffering strategy.  Do you have the same problem if you run your program from Terminal?

Comment: I had issues with permission for some reason trying to run from terminal, but I'm also not to keen on that. I did however figure out that (I think) I had been using g++ compiler, xcode updated recently, and now it isn't using the same compiler. When I switched IDEs and managed to use the g++ compiler it worked again. So I guess different compilers need the flush while others don't? That's why I was so confused when the answer was to flush the buffer, because I've never had to before.

Comment: The current version of Xcode is buggy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116829/xcode-thread-1-signal-sigstop

Answer (score 4):

When writing to a `std::ostream` in C++, you have to flush the buffer before anything will actually print to the console. You can do this either with `std::endl` or `std::flush`.

See the `std::ostream` reference [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/).

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string s;
    std::cout << "Flushed with a line break." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> s;
    std::cout << "Flushed with no line break." << std::flush;
    std::cin >> s;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've never had to use endl just to make output appear before, and flush simply is not doing anything. It still will not print anything until I've typed in an answer to the question.